# Как подключить два компа к сайту

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я привыкла верстать сайт с одного компа, через плагин liveReload(liveServer), но как мне сделать так, чтобы я могла на ноутбуке или телефоне смотреть сайт, а писать на компе.
Я пробовала через openServer, но ничего не получилось

Comment: Пробовать ещё. Других вариантов нет

Comment: Очень просто... Определи какой IP у девайса на котором сайт запущен и  введи этот IP на другом

Comment: Не забудь, что эти девайсы должны быть в одно локальной сети

Comment: попробуйте вести разработку через GitHub. Делаете изменения на одном компе, заливаете на гитхаб их, заходите на другом компе, пишите одну строку "скачивание изменений" в командной строке и вуаля - у вас все версии на всех девайсах. Гитхаб очень полезен для всех программистом, за некоторым исключением (1С, Abap и т.п.).